# How to save entry in Sequelize with hasOne relationship?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a model `Transaction` with a `hasMany` association to `StripePayment`.

I want to create a new `Transaction` with a related `StripePayment` like so:

```js
await models.Transaction.create({
  amount,
  stripePayment: {
    stripeId: paymentIntent.id,
    status: stripePaymentStatuses[status],
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  }
});
```

This creates a new Transaction but does **not** create the stripePayment.

My model is as such:

```js
// transaction model
class Transaction extends Model {
    
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.StripePayment, { 
      as: 'StripePayment',
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
  }
}

Transaction.init(
  {
    id:{ 
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    stripePaymentId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: true,
      foreignKey: true,
      references: {
        model: stripePayment,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Transaction',
  }
);
```

```js
// stripePayment
class StripePayment extends Model {
    
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Transaction, { 
      as: 'Transaction', 
      foreignKey: 'stripePaymentId' 
    });
  }
}

StripePayment.init(
  {
    id:{ 
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    // ...
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'StripePayment',
  }
);
```

I feel like the model is not aware of `stripePayment` when I pass it into the `create` method. Am I structuring this correctly?

How can I create a `Transaction` with a related `StripePayment`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to indicate the `include` option while calling the `create` method, see [creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html):

```js
await models.Transaction.create({
  amount,
  // pay attention: this prop should be named exactly as an alias of a model and because it's `hasMany` you should wrap it into an array
  StripePayment: [{
    stripeId: paymentIntent.id,
    status: stripePaymentStatuses[status],
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  }],
  include: [{
    model: StripePayment,  
    as: 'StripePayment',
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried adding that but still getting the same thing - no  `StripePayment` gets created.  I have made sure the key matches the alias of the model too which as you have is `StripePayment`. Does it matter that my foreign key in the `Transaction` model is `stripePaymentId`? Should that get automatically  populated with the newly created `stripePayment.id` value?

Comment: Look at updated answer, you have `hasMany` so you need to use an array